# Grafana, menu to get value and use in query

Tags: grafana

I need a little help here with Grafana...

I am trying to make a single stat which will be showing result from the query. The challenge for me here is that part of the query must be one of the fixed values (numbers) which user would select from menu picture. If user select Current Shift, value to query would be for example today, from 6:00 - 14:00.

Then pass the value to variable that query would use to limit range of data (for example in flux datasource).

I use Grafana 6.5.2 and Influxdb 1.7.9.

**Attching menu example**
[image]

**Attaching query, looking to input range**
|> range(start:2018-05-22T23:30:00Z, stop: 2018-05-23T00:00:00Z)
[image]

Appreciate help,
Salvq